# ArcObjects 10.3 Add Transparent Polygon to Map

Tags: c#, .net, arcgis, esri, arcobjects

This is an issue I have been trying to tackle for a while and decided to reach out for help. I am creating an ESRI ArcGIS Desktop Add-In that allows the user to draw a polygon and then have it added to the map. I am able to capture the polygon and add it to the map, the issue is the transparency. Currently and by default it is 100% opacity and solid. I want to make it around 50% opacity so the user can see the data behind it.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
     public static void AddPolygonToMap(IActiveView ActiveViewInstance, IGeometry NewGeo)
    {
        //Local Variable Declaration
        var fillShapeElement = default(IFillShapeElement);
        var element = default(IElement);
        var graphicsContainer = default(IGraphicsContainer);
        var simpleFilleSymbol = default(ISimpleFillSymbol);
        var newRgbColor = default(IRgbColor);
        var lineSymbol = default(ILineSymbol);

        //Use the IElement interface to set the Envelope Element's geo
        element = new PolygonElement();
        element.Geometry = NewGeo;

        //QI for the IFillShapeElement interface so that the symbol property can be set
        fillShapeElement = element as IFillShapeElement;

        //Create a new fill symbol
        simpleFilleSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol();

        //Create a new color marker symbol of the color black;
        newRgbColor = new RgbColor();
        newRgbColor.Red = 0;
        newRgbColor.Green = 0;
        newRgbColor.Blue = 0;

        //Create a new line symbol so that we can set the width outline
        lineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol();
        lineSymbol.Color = newRgbColor;
        lineSymbol.Width = 2;

        //Setup the Simple Fill Symbol
        simpleFilleSymbol.Color = newRgbColor;
        simpleFilleSymbol.Style = esriSimpleFillStyle.esriSFSHollow;
        simpleFilleSymbol.Outline = lineSymbol;
        fillShapeElement.Symbol = simpleFilleSymbol;

        //QI for the graphics container from the active view allows access to basic graphics layer
        graphicsContainer = ActiveViewInstance as IGraphicsContainer;

        //Add the new element at Z order 0
        graphicsContainer.AddElement((IElement)fillShapeElement, 0);

        //Show the new graphic
        ActiveViewInstance.Refresh();
    }
```

I know that this is possible somehow and I am sure it's just a line or two missing but any help would be much appreciated.

V/r,

Josh

Comment: I think this is a question for GIS.StackExchange

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thanks for the advice. I have moved this question to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155091/arcobjects-10-3-add-transparent-polygon-to-map

Comment: OP already moved this to GIS StackExchange, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155091/adding-transparent-polygon-to-map-using-arcobjects

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a graphic element that you are creating.  Graphic elements do not support transparency other than 100% transparent or 0% transparent.  This is outlined in the following documentation:

IColor.Transparency Property
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001w000000nt000000

```
For graphic elements, 0 for transparent and 255 for opaque are the only supported values.
```

I hope this helps!